# Use two things over GPIO SPI connection on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio, rfid

I have a 2.8" capacitive TFT screen from and a PN532 RFID reader from Adafruit.  The problem is, they both use SPI. When I use the RFID reader, the screen goes completely white and I have to restart the Pi to get the image back. I have to use the SPI interface on the reader so that I can use the Adafruit library to use it with Python. The screen going white isn't a problem as long as it's only when the RFID reader is in use. Is there anyway to "restart" the screen after using the RFID reader? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you giving each slave device on the SPI bus it's on chip select signal?

Comment: Why not use a second select line?

Comment: @datenwolf Okay I have no idea what this means which is part of the reason why I'm asking for help.  How do I go about changing chip select signals and lines exactly?

Comment: @The42ndTurtle: I hope my answer is more helpful, than the one of your not-so-helpful "groupie". The sass inside me wants to approve that edit. The good-guy-keep-everybody-happy in me just chuckles and lets others decide. I'm having a look at the Adafruit library now and maybe update my answer with further details.

Comment: OP, maybe consider to post this kind of question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For Raspberry Pi, [SPI0](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi) supports two channels with two CS pins, with CE0 on pin 24, and CE1 on pin 26.

Comment: @hcheung I put the cs on 26, then mosi = 6, miso = 16, and sclk = 11, and that didn't work.  I then realized that some of the pins were labeled with mosi, miso, and sclk, so I tried cs = 26, mosi = 10, miso = 9, and sclk = 11, and that didn't work either.  I really have no ideas what pins are actually usable for what, so do you have any suggestions for what pins I should use for the other 3?

Comment: did you enable the spi by editing the `/boot/config.txt`? Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50669030/edit) your post and add your code you done so far.

Comment: You are messing up the BCM notation with Board notation. You need to be consistent on whether you use BCM numbering or Board numbering. If you are using BCM, it should be 9 for MISO, 10 for MOSI, 11 for SCLK, 8 for CE0, and 9 for CE1. If you are using Board notation, it will be 21 for MISO, 19 for MOSI, 23 for SCLK, 24 for CE0, and 26 for CE1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SPI bus consists of 3 wires + 1 chip select signal per individually addressable slave on the SPI bus. Some devices, for example NeoPixels, many DACs, every shift register, etc. allow for daisy chaining, where a chain of devices may share a common chip select line.

However in your case you most certainly want to address devices that don't support daisy chaining. So each device requires an individual chip select line.

Let's first recapitulate, how a SPI bus works.

SPI transfers typically look like this

```
 /CS  ‾‾‾\___________________ . . . ___________/‾‾‾

 CLK  _____/‾‾‾\___/‾‾‾\___/‾ . . . ‾‾\____________

MOSI  =====X=======X=======X= . . . ===============

MISO  =========X=======X===== . . . ==X============
```

i.e. first the chip select (`/CS`) goes low, then the MOSI (master out → slave in) data lines are set to the next bit to be transferred and on the *rising* clock edge, and on the falling clock edge the slave reads that bit. Similarly on the *falling* clock edge the slave pulls the data line for the master to read on the rising endge.

However some devices require inverted clock polarity or expect different timings on MOSI/MISO. However the timings as outlined above are what works for most and which I've usually do when bitbanging.

The purpose of the `/CS` line is to delimit a bus transaction. A falling `/CS` begins a transaction, a rising one ends it. Which in essence means: **If a device does not see a falling `/CS` it will simply ignore everything that happens on the other lines.**

*So the first thing to wonder with a problem like your is: "Am I addressing my SPI slaves using different `/CS` signals, and if so, is the timing correct?"* The *must have* debugging tool for issues like that is an oscilloscope; preferrably one with 4 channels.

Your Raspberry-Pi has a couple of GPIO pins. Each of them technically can be used for a `/CS` signal. However often SPI transfers are controlled by devices and/or drivers which want to use a very specific pin for `/CS`. I'm not familiar with the Adafruit library, if it has such an expectancy. However if you can configure a "chip select" (CS), "slave select" (SS) or "chip enable" (CE) signal in the library, then this is where you specify, which GPIO you're using as `/CS` for the device in question.

If you can't configure it like that, there's always the option to use a hardwired AND gate on the `/CS` signal. The foolproof and robust solution is to use 74HCx series gate, however this comes with a lot of redundant wires. A slightly more elegant solution is to use a logic demultiplexer like a 74HC154 where you connect `/CS` to the `/EN` pins and using 4 GPIO lines can address to which of the 16 outputs the `/CS` signal gets routed.

However there's also a dead-cheap variant called *wired OR*. Remeber that the usual convention for `/CS` is to be pulled low. So what you can do is us a couple of resistors – and if you can't tristate your GPIO pins a few diodes – to force the `/CS` signal up for the devices you don't want to address. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection for details on that.

#### Update

So I've had a quick look at the library hosted here https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PN532 and right in the example there's this https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PN532/blob/feaf22f659731586adc9ded4af969bb256969ed3/examples/readmifare.py#L28

```
# Setup how the PN532 is connected to the Raspbery Pi/BeagleBone Black.
# It is recommended to use a software SPI connection with 4 digital GPIO pins.

# Configuration for a Raspberry Pi:
CS   = 18
MOSI = 23
MISO = 24
SCLK = 25
```

So not only is this library in question using not tied to a dedicated SPI peripheral, you can actually freely configure which GPIO pins to use, to talk to the RFID reader.

Comment: The library by Adafruit allows for the CS, MOSI, MISO, and SCLK to be changed.  Is there a limitation on to which pins can act as what or can I just change them all to pins that won't overlap with the screen?  I know that there are power and ground and stuff like that, so it can't just be any pin, but I don't know if there's any variation as far as the data pins are concerned.  Thanks a lot for your help.  This is my first time doing something like this so I really appreciate it.

Comment: @The42ndTurtle: any GPIO pin that's not used otherwise should be fine. Taking https://pinout.xyz/ any BCMxx pin without special function (stated in parentheses) should work.

Comment: I tried hooking it up so cs = 16, mosi = 5, miso = 6, and sclk = 26 and it cannot detect the reader.  Pretty much all the other not taken pins are being used by the screen so they were really the only options.

Comment: @The42ndTurtle: which numbering scheme did you use? Did you use BCM numbering or pin-header numbering? Unfortunately I don't own the hardware you have, so I can't reproduce immediately. But tomorrow let me hook up a scope to an R-Pi and see what configuring the library like that does.

Comment: I believe I used the BCM numbering. If that's the little numbers next to the BCM then that's what I used.  That is the one I am supposed to use right?

Comment: @The42ndTurtle: I think so. But let me double check tomorrow, when I again have access to a R-Pi and a scope.

Comment: Okay I got it working.  I put cs = 7, mosi = 20, miso = 19, and sclk = 21 and it worked.  Thanks for your help.